# Python Flask image manipulation librery

Tags: python-3.x, image, flask

I google it, but the number of library are overwhelming,
I'm looking for a image manipulation library, written in Python that I can implement in Flask;

I need to solve this simple sets of operations:

1. Upload the image.
2. Resize / scale the image (maintained the proportions).
3. Save the new image in a specific path with a specific name.
4. Remove the original image.

Also I notice that many promising project are unchanged in the last 2 years....

Comment: Have you looked into [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: First of all thanks for your suggestion, yes I looked into it, seems to be an all around lib, but I'm still looking for something simpler, do you know something less complex?

Comment: I don't know of a simpler method for resizing/scaling, sorry.

Comment: Pillow is probably the easiest https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open